# Очередь выполнения функций

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код (аккордеон):

```
jQuery('#collapse' + something + ':not(.in)').collapse('show');
item.addClass('curshow');
jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop: item.offset().top}, 500);
```

При игре на этом аккордеоне, со 2-го раза почему-то, из-за асинхронности js неверно определяет `item.offset().top`. Он берет значение до `.collapse('show')`. Как правильно организовать очередь? Пробовал делать так:

```
jQuery('#collapse' + something + ':not(.in)').collapse('show').parents("html, body").animate({scrollTop: item.offset().top}, 500); // вообще не работает
```

Так:

```
...
item.addClass('curshow').parents("html, body").animate({scrollTop: item.offset().top}, 500); //неверно определяет
```

И так:

```
...
jQuery("html, body").queue(function() {
    jQuery(this).animate({scrollTop: item.offset().top}, 500);
    jQuery(this).dequeue();
});
```

Comment: Пример на jsfiddle совсем не повредил бы

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в том, что второй раз вы пытаетесь запустить до того, как отработает анимация. Воспользуйтесь встроенным коллбэком complete, вот так:

```
$(...).animate({...}, 500, function () {
    // complete callback
    // вот тут анимация уже завершена
});
```

Comment: Анимация - это последнее, что мне нужно выполнить. Как раз при выполнении анимации (при передаче параметра) - ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Помог таймаут:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#collapse' + something ).parent('div').offset().top}, 500);
}, 300);
```